# Upload a csv file in apps script from google drive blocked by CORS policy

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, d3.js, google-drive-api, cors

I want to generate a D3.js tree from a google sheet.

In the exemple I followed, the tree is generated with a csv.
So, I have generated with apps script a csv file on my google drive from a google sheet and now, I try to load it like this example:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script>
d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/data_hierarchy_1level.csv', function(data) {console.log(data)})
</script>
```

Here it works fine but when I try to load my own csv from google drive, I have with this code:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script>
d3.csv('https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1S9_KA87o_i7PjHILicXX21mlVeQc1jIA', function(data) {console.log(data)})
</script>
```

the following error messages:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1S9_KA87o_i7PjHILicXX21mlVeQc1jIA' from origin 'https://n-mvggraccraz7qqhyhidnzi7cecuqlcodyfxsjjq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

VM1794 d3.v4.js:11472          GET https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1S9_KA87o_i7PjHILicXX21mlVeQc1jIA net::ERR_FAILED 303

I have checked the 2 files. They seems to be the same. I do not see where is the error.
Could-you explain how to use a file from the drive like any file with an URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current stage, it seems that when the endpoint of webContentLink like `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=###&export=download` is used, the error like `has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` occurs. In order to avoid this, how about the following patterns?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the API key is used. When the API key is used, this issue can be removed. You can see how to retrieve the API key at [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys). In your URL, it becomes as follows.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}?alt=media&key={APIkey}
```

When this URL is used, it becomes the following script.

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script>
d3.csv('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}?alt=media&key={APIkey}', function(data) {console.log(data)})
</script>
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the API key is not used. When I saw your question, I noticed `In the exemple I followed, the tree is generated with a csv. So, I have generated with apps script a csv file on my google drive from a google sheet and now`. From this, I understood that you want to use the CSV data retrieved from Spreadsheet. If my understanding is correct, I thought that your goal can be achieved directly using the Spreadsheet. The flow of this is as follows.

1. Publish Spreadsheet as web pages. [Ref](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308870?hl=en)

   - By this, you can retrieve the URL like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml`.
2. Modify URL.

   - Please modify the above-retrieved URL as follows.

     ```
       https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pub?output=csv
     ```
   - In this URL, the 1st sheet of the Spreadsheet is used. For example, when you want to use the other sheet, please modify it as follows using the sheet ID.

     ```
       https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pub?output=csv&gid={sheetId}
     ```

When this URL is used for your script, it becomes as follows.

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script>
d3.csv('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pub?output=csv', function(data) {console.log(data)})
</script>
```

Comment: I have used the second solution. It works well. You perfectly understood my goal and you gave me a huge shortcut and a bretter solution. Thank you very much!
Just if someone uses this solution be careful. By default it takes 5 minutes to update data when you do a modification. So do not be surprised if you do a change and do not see the difference.

Comment: @user2964288 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.